# How to assign a display order of the tables in a single report in ssrs 2008

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a report in ssrs 2008 including 2 different tables.

```
TABLE A    TABLE B
```

Both table are grouped by Name by adding a rowGroup. Note that there is also a page break "between each instance of the group" is enabled. So, When I run this report, it is running like:

```
------Page 1------
Name:X      Name:X
TABLE A     TABLE B
------Page 2------
Name:Y      Name:Y
TABLE A     TABLE B
------Page 3------
Name:AllName   Name:AllNames
TABLE A     TABLE B
```

However, I would like to put the table in an order. When Table A ends for all its group, then I want Table B to start. Example:

```
------Page 1------
Name:X     
TABLE A     
------Page 2------
Name:Y 
TABLE A
------Page 3------
Name:AllNames 
TABLE A       
------Page 4------
Name:X
TABLE B
------Page 5------
Name:Y
TABLE B
------Page 6------
Name:AllNames
TABLE B
```

How can I provide this? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you try putting a rectangle with page break between both tables?. Also  place table B below table A.

Comment: I think no since I dont know about rectangles:) I appreciate if you detail it for me.

Comment: Thanks a lot friend. Working!! I have been trying to do it for 4 hours, happy to learn at the end! When you add an answer I'll assign it as correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can drag (or add) a Rectangle from Toolbox window to your report surface (like a tablix), then place the rectangle between the tables.

[image]

Right click it and select Rectangle properties, select `Add a page break before`. It will put a page break before render the rectangle.

I hope it has been useful.

Comment: May I ask if there is any way to make it work when we put the tables like left-right (as in the question) instead of top-bottom (as ur answer) ?

Comment: The result would be the same because page break works vertically as my answer and the expected result in your question.

Comment: When I put the tables left-right and place the rectangle between them, this is not working in that case. It is bringing like -> (Page1)Name:X TableA - (Page2)Name:All TableA  Name:X TableB - (Page3) Name:All Table B

Comment: But if you put the tables up-down the result is like the example of the expected table in your question.

Comment: Hey. I have an issue over there which is related to this issue. I appreciate if you check for me when you have free time. Regards. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36865657/how-to-change-order-of-the-table-displays-page-number-to-keep-the-tables-seque