# How to change order of the table displays (page number) to keep the tables sequential

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a report in ssrs 2008, which includes 2 tables and 1 rectangle to keep them in separated pages like:

```
Table 1
rectangle (it is blank - page break before is selected from its properties)
Table 2
```

Both the tables are grouped by NAME, in their Row Group. Therefore, when I run the report the output is like:

```
------Page 1-----------
Table 1 (Name:John)
------Page 2-----------
Table 2 (Name: John)
------Page 3-----------
Table 1 (Name: Mike)
------Page 4-----------
Table 2 (Name: Mike)
------Page 5-----------
Table 1 (Name: Alex)
------Page 6-----------
Table 2 (Name: Alex)
...
```

What I want is to change the page order and keep the records sequential based on the table, not the group. Desired output example:

```
------Page 1-----------
Table 1 (Name: John)
------Page 2-----------
Table 1 (Name: Mike)
------Page 3-----------
Table 1 (Name: Alex)
------Page 4-----------
Table 2 (Name: John)
------Page 5-----------
Table 2 (Name: Mike)
------Page 6-----------
Table 2 (Name: Alex)
...
```

How can I provide this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that your tables aren't in another table (list)? It should normally show all the records from table 1 and then table 2. From your description, it sounds like you have a list that is sorted by name that the other two tables are in.

Comment: Nope, they r not in another list or something.

Comment: What you're describing is not the default table behavior. I would suggest deleting that rectangle as I suspect it's causing the issue. You can set a page break at the end of the first table instead.